# Are there any Wi-Fi modules for the Arduino Uno that may connect to an external Wi-Fi Antenna?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, shields, web-server

I have an Arduino Uno I need to connect to Wi-Fi to make HTTP POST Requests to a Raspberry Pi Web Server.

The Arduino is located only about 30 feet from the AP, but there is a brick wall in the line of sight, and it is in a metal outdoor enclosure. For that reason, I wanted to attach an external Wi-Fi Antenna which would stick out a sealed hole in the enclosure.

I was contemplating using an ESP8266 Wi-Fi module, but it does not look like there is an easy way to attach the antenna.

What would be the best Wi-Fi module to which I could attach an external antenna for an Arduino Uno?

Comment: https://robotdyn.com/wifi-d1-mini-esp8266-dev-board-usb-cp2104.html do you see the antenna connector?

Comment: @Juraj Thanks. That might be a better option. It's a lot more self-contained, it's cleaner, and I won't need a load level converter.

Comment: the same in Uno format https://robotdyn.com/wifi-d1-r2-esp8266-dev-board-32m-flash.html. but I can't recommend it. both, the on-board antenna and the connector are connected. I think, it causes problems and there are no instructions how to cut connection to one of them

Comment: on the mini version the external antenna connector is not connected. you would need to re-solder the 0 ohm 'resistor' that connects the on-board antenna to soldering points connecting the external antenna connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are variants of ESP8266-based modules which include a connection for an external antenna. The ESP-02, ESP-05 and ESP-07 modules all feature a U.FL socket.

Effectively, they are an ESP8266 mounted on a carrier board with a U.FL socket.

If you already have some code to suit an ESP8266-based module, this will avoid having to rewrite for a different unit.